# Getting the count of child elements who match a certain text using protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a parent `<div>` in a non Angular page. Inside that parent `<div>` there are many child `<div>`s. In those child `<div>`s I have many tags with data. The structure of the HTML is as follow:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User16</p>
        <p class="project-name">Manager</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User16</p>
        <p class="project-name">Manager</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User15</p>
        <p class="project-name">Developer</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User14</p>
        <p class="project-name">Developer</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User13</p>
        <p class="project-name">Tester</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User12</p>
        <p class="project-name">Terster</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User11</p>
        <p class="project-name">Developer</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col206">
        <p class="name">User10</p>
        <p class="project-name">Support</p>
        <p class="telefone"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to test the project using Protractor and get the count of those elements whose project name is tester. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now there is no built-in locator to perform easily what you want to do. There is one locator that allow us to search by text but it is only for [button element](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/locators.js#L127).

I proposed a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/488) to be able to search elements with css selector and text but it is not accepted yet.

Meanwhile, you can build your own specific locator:

```
by.addLocator('projectName', function() {
    var projectSelector = '.row div'; // probably need some refinement
    var projectName = arguments[0];
    var using = arguments[1] || document;
    var elements = using.querySelectorAll(projectSelector); 
    var matches = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var elementText = element.innerText || element.textContent;
        if (elementText === projectName) {
            matches.push(element);
        }
    }

    return matches;
});
```

And then you can count like this:

```
element.all(by.projectName("Tester")).count()
```